# Is annotation resolved in python at runtime? Is it allowed to be not defined?

Tags: python

```py
>>> x : foo = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

```py
>>> def add(x):
      y : bar = 1      # No Error
      return x + y
>>> add(3)
4
```

Clearly, the name `bar` is not read, but `foo` is read at runtime. Is this a known thing? What are the current conditions on annotations being defined/not defined? In future versions, is this going to be mandatory for annotations to be defined everywhere?

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs:

[typing.TYPE_CHECKING](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING):

> Type annotations for local variables are not evaluated

So that explains why your second example doesn't raise an error.

If you need to forward declare an annotation (i.e. you want to use a symbol that will get defined later in your code), you can use a string literal, e.g.:

```
x: 'foo' = 3
```

Comment: Why does the interpreter try to read the annotation in the first example (Does the language ref says it MUST be defined - and so, this would just be an additional check just to fulfil the language reference)? Or, is there a use case where the annotation being undefined can lear to panic at runtime?

Comment: In general, annotations get eval'd like any other expression; that's why you can create aliases for types by assigning the type to a name and then using the name in place of the type.  Trying to eval an undeclared name will generally raise a `NameError`.